# How do I keep an edit button hidden in a formview after using a filterexpression?

Tags: asp.net, formview

I'm trying to have a user/admin scenario for editing a formview. What I have is the Edit buttons in the formview be visible=true by default. Then I use a statement which says if the role is not equal to admin, then set the visibility to false for the edit button. It works like it should, when I click around, do postbacks, etc. the items stay hidden if the user is and admin...except when I use a dropdown list for filtering, which uses a statement like `dataSource1.FilterExpression = ("ID=" + ddl1.SelectedValue)`.

Whether I set the default visibility to true or false for the formview edit linkbutton, when using the FilterExpression, it changes the visibility of what I don't want it to be. It is because the FilterExpression sets the visibility of the control to whatever the default visibility property of the control is set to.

Below is some code as an example of what I mean. Please help!

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    string role;
    role = "client";
    LinkButton editGeneralOverview = (LinkButton)formViewGeneralOverview.FindControl("EditButton");

if (role != "admin"))
{
    editGeneralOverview.Visible = false;
}

if (ddlIDFilter.SelectedValue != "-- ALL --")
{
    dataSourceGeneralOverview.FilterExpression = ("ID=" + ddlIDFilter.SelectedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide it in the `FormView`s DataBound event:

```
protected void formViewGeneralOverview_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton editGeneralOverview = (LinkButton)formViewGeneralOverview.FindControl("EditButton");

    if (role != "admin"))
    {
        editGeneralOverview.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

This way your visibility setting gets (re)applied after the FilterExpression has already taken effect.

Note: in case you do not know, you can attach this event to the `FormView` in the markup by setting the OnDataBound property.  Like this:

```
<asp:FormView ID="formViewGeneralOverview" 
    OnDataBound="formViewGeneralOverview_DataBound" 
    ...whatever other propeties you have >
    ...templates and junk...
</asp:FormView>
```